# Unable to trigger the button inside bootstrap tool-tip or popover

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am unable to trigger event on a button which is inside a bootstrap tooltip. On click of that tooltip i need to open a modal-popup.

Please find the JSFiddle `"https://jsfiddle.net/wumqynez/1/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the class of `hide` on the bootstrap popover content, which is the correct way to go about this, but in doing so I think you need to use event delegation in order to access the content so you should use `$(document).on` to trigger your jquery click event.  So your click event should look like the following:

```
$(document).on("click", "#test", function() {
    alert('The paragraph was clicked.');
});
```